# How to assign macro to a table column in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

Currently I'm creating a macro that reads data from a table column, Asset No. The data is obtained through drop-down menu via data validation from another table in another sheet, DieMaster.

It will then perform Index and Match to find the matching data from DieMaster and insert it into Description column.

In addition, Upon obtaining data, the table column will then copy and paste as value to get the data only. That way the formula won't slow down filter searches.

This is what I have come up with.

```
Sub convert()

Dim osh As Worksheet
Set osh = ActiveSheet
osh.Range("ProjectEntry[Description]").Formula = "=IF(ISNA(INDEX(DieMaster,MATCH(B4,DieMaster[Asset No],FALSE),2)),"""",INDEX(DieMaster,MATCH(B4,DieMaster[Asset No],FALSE),2))"
osh.Range("ProjectEntry[Description]").Copy
osh.Range("ProjectEntry[Description]").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

I have tested the macro and it works perfectly. However the issue I have now is trying to assign the macro to Asset No column. My plan is to have it so that when a value is selected in a cell within the Asset No column via aforementioned drop-down menu, it will automatically show me the data for description.

Since I cannot assign macro to column using the traditional method, is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`Worksheet_Change`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-change-event-excel) Event to accomplish this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(Target as Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Me.ListObjects("ProjectEntry").ListColumns("AssetNo").DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then 

     With Me.Range("ProjectEntry[Description]") 
        .Formula = "=IF(ISNA(INDEX(DieMaster,MATCH(B4,DieMaster[Asset No],FALSE),2)),"""",INDEX(DieMaster,MATCH(B4,DieMaster[Asset No],FALSE),2))"
        .Value = .Value
     End With

End If

End Sub
```

My syntax may be slightly off (since I am not on my normal computer), but it will get you close enough to tweak on your own.

Comment: I tried doing some tweaks to the code you gave me. But I got this compile error instead.

Comment: Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name.

Comment: what does it mean?

Comment: never mind. All I had to do was add ByVal in Private Sub. Now it works fine now. Thanks.

Comment: Although now I seem to notice that the process is taking a while. Is there an alternative which is faster?

Comment: never mind. all I had to do was repeat the step until  the majority of the formulas are in VBA. now the speed is not frustratingly slow now. tqvm.

Comment: @hjh93 - I was away for about a week. Glad you got it working. You can also turn calculations on/off as needed to speed up process. Only calculate at end of code for example.